# Check the minimum by iterating one row in a dataframe over all the rows in another dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, uber-api

Let's say I have the following two dataframes:

```
DF1:
+----------+----------+----------+
|     Place|Population|    IndexA|     
+----------+----------+----------+
|         A|       Int|       X_A|
|         B|       Int|       X_B|
|         C|       Int|       X_C|
+----------+----------+----------+

DF2:
+----------+----------+
|      City|    IndexB|     
+----------+----------+
|         D|       X_D|      
|         E|       X_E|   
|         F|       X_F|  
|      ....|      ....|
|        ZZ|      X_ZZ|
+----------+----------+
```

The dataframes above are normally of much larger size.

I want to determine to which `City`(`DF2`) the shortest distance is from every `Place` from `DF1`. The distance can be calculated based on the index. So for every row in `DF1`, I have to iterate over every row in `DF2` and look for the shortest distances based on the calculations with the indexes. For the distance calculation there is a function defined:

```
val distance = udf(
      (indexA: Long, indexB: Long) => {
        h3.instance.h3Distance(indexA, indexB)
      })
```

I tried the following:

```
val output =  DF1.agg(functions.min(distance(col("IndexA"), DF2.col("IndexB"))))
```

But this, the code compiles but I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s)
> H3Index#220L missing from Places#316,Population#330,IndexAx#338L in operator !Aggregate
> [min(if ((isnull(IndexA#338L) OR isnull(IndexB#220L))) null else
> UDF(knownnotnull(IndexA#338L), knownnotnull(IndexB#220L))) AS min(UDF(IndexA, IndexB))#346].

So I suppose I do something wrong with iterating over each row in `DF2` when taking one row from `DF1` but I couldn't find a solution.

What am I doing wrong? And am I in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because the index column you are using only exists in `DF2` and not `DF1` where you are attempting to perform the aggregation.

In order to make this field accessible and determine the distance from all points, you would need to

1. Cross join `DF1` and `Df2` to have every index of `Df1` matching every index of `DF2`
2. Determine the distance using your udf
3. Find the min on this new cross joined udf with the distances

This may look like :

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, min, udf}

val distance = udf(
      (indexA: Long, indexB: Long) => {
        h3.instance.h3Distance(indexA, indexB)
      })

val resultDF = DF1.crossJoin(DF2)
    .withColumn("distance", distance(col("IndexA"), col("IndexB")))
    //instead of using a groupby then matching the min distance of the aggregation with the initial df. I've chosen to use a window function min to determine the min_distance of each group (determined by Place) and filter by the city with the min distance to each place
    .withColumn("min_distance", min("distance").over(Window.partitionBy("Place")))
    .where(col("distance") === col("min_distance"))
    .drop("min_distance")
```

This will result in a dataframe with columns from both dataframes and and additional column `distance`.

***NB.** Your current approach which is comparing every item in one df to every item in another df is an expensive operation. If you have the opportunity to filter early (eg joining on heuristic columns, i.e. other columns which may indicate a place may be closer to a city), this is recommended.*

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: This method worked. It was indeed very an expensive operation. But after efficiently using `.cache()`, it really minimized the costs. Thanks @ggordon

Comment: One more thing, the minimum distance is between place A and city B. But the solution above only shows the minimum distance, and not to which city the minimum distance is. How should I do that?

Comment: The city with minimum distance is in the `City` column of final dataframe

Answer (score 0):

If you have only a few cities (less than or around 1000), you can avoid `crossJoin` and `Window` shuffle by collecting cities in an array and then perform distance computation for each place using this collected array:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array_min, col, struct, transform, typedLit, udf}

val citiesIndexes = df2.select("City", "IndexB")
  .collect()
  .map(row => (row.getString(0), row.getLong(1)))

val result = df1.withColumn(
  "City",
  array_min(
    transform(
      typedLit(citiesIndexes),
      x => struct(distance(col("IndexA"), x.getItem("_2")), x.getItem("_1"))
    )
  ).getItem("col2")
)
```

This piece of code works for Spark 3 and greater. If you are on a Spark version smaller than 3.0, you should replace `array_min(...).getItem("col2")` part by an user-defined function.